# Getting "ImportError: cannot import name register_translation"

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have installed the necessary packages but I still cannot import the module.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import register_translation
from skimage.feature.register_translation import _upsampled_dft
from scipy.ndimage import fourier_shift
```

Comment: Did you install it in the right enviorment?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is your development environment? Where/How did you install scikit-image? How are you running this code snippet?

Comment: spyder is my development environment. I installed scikit-image with terminal of ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

This is deprecated:
from skimage.feature import register_translation

Use skimage.registration.phase_cross_correlation instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certain that you installed skimage in the system Python environment instead of the one used by Spyder. To check this, type `python` in the terminal, then `import sys; print(sys.prefix)`. Then, in the Spyder IPython console, try `import sys; print(sys.prefix)` as well. If the prefixes don't match, they are not using the same Python.

To install scikit-image in the Python environment used by Spyder, if your Spyder prefix is, say, `/home/me/miniconda`, then you would install into that environment with the terminal command: `/home/me/miniconda/bin/python -m pip install scikit-image`. (That is, append `/bin/python` to the output of `sys.prefix`.)